# Why is my website not loading properly on Iphones?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone

I am very new in this field, I'm learning about front-end development, and this is my second project and I don't know what it's the problem.

I recently created [this website](https://codepen.io/Arielink/full/WOagzY/) :

```js
   
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').scrollspy({target:".navbar", offset: 50});
        $('nav a').smoothScroll({offset: -40});
    });
```

```css
        body {
        position: relative,
    }
    body, html {
        height: 100%;
    }
    .div {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
        color: white;
    }
    
    .navbar {
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        font-size: 18px;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
        
    }
    
    .navbar>.container .navbar-brand, .navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand {
        color: white;
        font-family: "Oleo Script", cursive;
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    
    i:hover {
        opacity: 0.4;
    }
    
    .bg { 
        position: relative;
        background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Arielink90/project/master/image/pexels-photo-261577.jpeg");
        height: 100%; 
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
    }
    
    .text-stylin {
        font-family: 'Oleo Script', cursive;
        font-size: 50px;
        letter-spacing: 5px;
       
    }
    
    #front-end {
        letter-spacing: 10px;
        font-size: 25px;
        
        
    }
    
    .centered {
      position:absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 45%;
      width: 100%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50);
    }
    
    .centered a {
        color: white;
    }
    
    .header-icons {
         font-size: 40px;
         color: white;
         letter-spacing: 20px;
    }
    
    #about {
        background-color: rgb( 151, 150, 145);
    }
    
    
    .position {
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }
    
    .img-circle {
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 200px;
        position: inherit;
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
    }
    
    .down {
        display: grid;
        top: 30px
        
    }
    
    #hello {
        font-family: monospace;
    }
    
    #presentation {
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: justify;
     }
    
    #hayao:hover {
        opacity: .5;
    }
    
    #project {
        margin-bottom: 42px;
    }
    
    #work {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 40px
    }
    
    
    #project .col-sm-4 {
        padding: 0;
        
    }
    #project .col-sm-4 {
        padding: 20px;
        
    }
    
    .zoom {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .polaroid img {
     -webkit-transform: scale(1);
     transform: scale(1);
     -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
     transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    }
    .polaroid:hover img {
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
     transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    
    div.polaroid {
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
    .polaroid-text {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        
    }
    
    footer {
        background-color: rgb( 16, 16, 16);
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
    
    .color {
        color: white
    }
    
    .icons {
        font-size: 40px;
        letter-spacing: 20px;
    }
    
    .icons a {
        color: white;
    }
```

```html
     <div id="home" class="bg">
             <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Portfolio</a>
        </div> 
    
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#project">Work</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
            <div class="centered">
                <h2 class="text-stylin">Ariel Yanes</h2>
                <h4 id="front-end">Front End Web Developer</h4>
                   <div class="header-icons">
                    <i class="fa fa-github-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.com/arielink90" Target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-free-code-camp" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ariel-yanes-albuerne-7a61b4121/" Target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://codepen.io/Arielink/" Target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-codepen" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="about" class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row position">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img class="img-circle" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Arielink90/project/master/image/FaceQ2017_06_29_12_07_01.png" alt="avatar image"/>
                </div>
                <div id="presentation" class="col-sm-8 down">
                    <h2 id="hello" class="text-center">Hello and Welcome to my page!</h2>
                    <p >I'm a front web developer student. Is being two-month sense I start in freeCodeCamp. I have learned a lot and I now the what a like is elegant and minimalistic web designs, that help the user to have a pleasant experience</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
        <div id="project" class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <h2 id="work" class="text-center">My Work</h2>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="polaroid">
                        <div class="zoom">
                            <a href="https://codepen.io/Arielink/full/GEWQwm/"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Arielink90/project/master/image/CodePen%20-%20Hayao%20Miyazaki%20Tribute%20Page%20-%20Google%20Chrome%207_2_2017%2012_37_27%20PM.png" alt="project image"/></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="polaroid-text">
                            <h4>Tribute Page</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                   <div class="polaroid">
                       <div class="zoom">
                           <img class="img-responsive" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Arielink90/project/master/image/Personal%20Portfolio%20-%20Google%20Chrome%207_2_2017%2012_38_37%20PM.png" alt="project image"/>
                       </div>
                       <div class="polaroid-text">
                           <h4>My Portfolio</h4>
                       </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <div class="polaroid">
                      <div class="zoom">
                          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Arielink90/project/master/image/Creative%20-%20Start%20Bootstrap%20Theme%20-%20Google%20Chrome%207_2_2017%2012_56_01%20PM.png" alt="project image"/>
                      </div>
                      <div class="polaroid-text">
                          <h4>Future Poject</h4>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    <footer id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="color text-center">
                <h2>Contact Me</h2>
                <p>Name: Ariel Yanes Albuerne</p>
                <p>E-mail: xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com</p>
                <p>Phone Number: xxx-xxx-xxxx</p>
                  <div class="icons text-center">
                     <i class="fa fa-github-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.com/arielink90" Target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-free-code-camp" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ariel-yanes-albuerne-7a61b4121/" Target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://codepen.io/Arielink/" Target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-codepen" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
               </div>
            </div>
              
        </div>
       
    </footer>
```

It's loading fine in computers and Android devices but not in iPhones and I can't find the reason. 
If someone can explain me the problem or give me any idea, it will be very helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: How does it render on an iPad? What version of iOS is the iPhone, what version of Safari is on that iPhone? Is it consistent across all browsers on that iPhone?

Comment: I don't have an iPad, so I did not try on that device, The iOs version is 10.3.2 and about the behavior on different browsers, I am testing on safari and Chrome and it's kind of different on each one, but still is wrong.

Comment: The other thing and I don't know if is something to consider is that I am testing the website from codePen. I am just open the full site version in the codePen link (https://codepen.io/Arielink/full/WOagzY/)

Comment: Have you tried to load up a working codepen similar to yours on the device? I think the first step would be is to make sure Safari on iOs handles codepens OK. If you cna determine codepen is not the issue can you further describe the "but not in iPhones" part? such as... "I get a blank page" or "my text wraps way too mch" or "My content is cut off"

Comment: I think that "why is a site not working?" is very wide question to be asked here. You should break your question into little, targetable problems. Like "Why is the home screen too large?" or "Why is the navbar not showing?" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because it is designed for larger screens and it kinda freaks out when there is a smaller screen use a media query in css like this

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 200px) {
    // insert css here that you want to be used when the screen size is bigger than 200px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line to your head section:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: is there, you don't see it be cos I'm using codepen , and you add that to the settings of the page

Comment: Oh true sorry, I didn't check your settings.

Comment: that's ok, I am testing everything that everyone recommends me but still nothing